# DSpace jspui on Google Kubernetes deployment fails after GKE upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, google-kubernetes-engine, dspace

We have a deployment of DSpace 6.3 to Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) that has always worked perfectly. However, when we upgraded GKE from v1.12.7-gke.24 to 1.14.10-gke.50 the container suddenly failed. The change to the k8s version is the only difference between the working and failing k8s nodes. Locally built docker containers work fine. We are deploying other DSpace modules in separate containers (e.g. solr) they work fine, only the jspui module is failing.

DSpace branch "dspace-6_x" tag "dspace-6.3"

Docker image: tomcat:8-alpine

Deployment via gitlab CI/CD pipeline

The failure is caused by the Spring Loader falling over when calling the early loading of the various DSpace factory service singleton pattern beans. This results in a 404 error when loading the site, as the web app has failed to initialise.

Error message in /usr/local/tomcat/log/localhost.YYYY-MM-dd.log:

```
28-Oct-2020 23:47:18.668 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart 
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
[org.dspace.servicemanager.servlet.DSpaceKernelServletContextListener]
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure during filter init: Failed to startup the DSpace Service 
Manager: failure starting up spring service manager: Error creating bean with name 
'org.dspace.app.sherpa.submit.SHERPASubmitService' defined in URL 
[jar:file:/dspace/webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/lib/dspace-api-6.3.jar!/spring/spring-dspace-addon-sherpa-services.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.dspace.app.sherpa.submit.SHERPASubmitConfigurationService' while setting 
bean property'configuration'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.dspace.app.sherpa.submit.SHERPASubmitConfigurationService' defined in 
file [/dspace/config/spring/api/sherpa.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 
'org.dspace.app.sherpa.submit.MetadataValueISSNExtractor#1b511285' of type 
[org.dspace.app.sherpa.submit.MetadataValueISSNExtractor] while setting bean property 
'issnItemExtractors' with key [0]; nestedexception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'org.dspace.app.sherpa.submit.MetadataValueISSNExtractor#1b511285': Injection of autowired dependencies 
failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire 
field: public org.dspace.content.service.ItemService 
org.dspace.app.sherpa.submit.MetadataValueISSNExtractor.itemService; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'org.dspace.content.ItemServiceImpl#0': Injection of autowireddependencies failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected 
org.dspace.handle.service.HandleService org.dspace.content.DSpaceObjectServiceImpl.handleService; ...
```

The "failure starting up spring service manager" error message is raised at:

org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceServiceManager
(\dspace-services\src\main\java\org\dspace\servicemanager\DSpaceServiceManager.java line 215)

in a catch statement from line 212 which calls:

org.dspace.servicemanager.spring.SpringServiceManager.startup()
(\dspace-services\src\main\java\org\dspace\servicemanager\spring\SpringServiceManager.java line 177)

which uses the Spring framework to early load the factory beans.

Our first thought was that the new k8s version may need more memory. So we increased the Tomcat memory to 4GB from 1.5GB. This did not resolve the issue.

We have studied the release notes for the intervening versions of GKE between our upgrades but found nothing helpful.

We have tried using other Tomcat docker images, to no avail. So, we do not believe it is a problem with the OS.

Remote Debugging won't connect to Tomcat fast enough to trap the exceptions. We tried the Google Cloud Debugger for Java, but Alpine Linux is missing some required libraries. Regardless, I don't believe we'd find anything more helpful than the error message that is being logged.

If anyone has any ideas, we'd be most grateful.

Our production k8s config yaml file:

```
ingress:
  hosts:
    - our.url.uts.edu.au

database:
  secret: our_password
  name: our_db_name
  host: "our.db.instance.url"
  port: "5432"

dspace:
  env:
    - name: DSPACE_HOSTNAME
      value: our.url.uts.edu.au
    - name: SOLR_PORT
      value: "8080"
      # Include colon if port is specified
    - name: DSPACE_PORT
      value: ""
    - name: MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS
      value: "50"
    - name: "MAX_IDLE_DB_CONNECTIONS"
      value: "30"
    - name: INITIAL_DB_CONNECTIONS
      value: "20"
    - name: S3_ASSETSTORE_SUBFOLDER
      value: "our_folder"
    - name: S3_CONNECTION_TTL
      value: "120000"
    - name: S3_MAX_CONNECTIONS
      value: "50"
    - name: REST_EVENT_WEBHOOK_URL
      value: http://our.rest.service.url/dspace/v2/webhook
    - name: UTSLIB_FRAMEWORK_DSPACE_TOKEN
      value: OUR_TOKEN
    - name: CATALINA_OPTS
      value: "-Xms1512m -Xmx1512m"

  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "1640Mi"
      cpu: 100m
    limits:
      memory: "1896Mi"
      cpu: "450m"

solr:
  pvc:
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
    annotations: {}
    size: 35Gi

  env:
    - name: CATALINA_OPTS
      value: "-Xms3904m -Xmx3904m -XX:+UseG1GC"

  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "4032Mi"
      cpu: 50m
    limits:
      memory: "4096Mi"
      cpu: "800m"

cron:
  env:
    - name: SOLR_PORT
      value: "8080"
    - name: MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS
      value: "3"
    - name: MAX_IDLE_DB_CONNECTIONS
      value: "1"
    - name: INITIAL_DB_CONNECTIONS
      value: "0"
    - name: S3_ASSETSTORE_SUBFOLDER
      value: "our_folder"
    - name: S3_CONNECTION_TTL
      value: "120000"
    - name: S3_MAX_CONNECTIONS
      value: "50"
    - name: JAVA_OPTS
      value: "-Xms32m -Xmx384m"
    - name: REST_EVENT_WEBHOOK_URL
      value: http://our.rest.service.url/dspace/v2/webhook
    - name: UTSLIB_FRAMEWORK_DSPACE_TOKEN
      value: OUR_TOKEN
```

Our Dockerfiles are divided into build and runtime processes.
Dockerfile.build

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8

# Modules that should be excluded from depdendency resolution
ARG EXCLUDE_MODULES=!dspace-rdf,!dspace-sword,!dspace-xmlui,!dspace-xmlui-mirage2

ENV DSPACE_VERSION=6.3 \
    DSPACE_SHA1=e60db8dee2726933fcc7b7949c16757a510a79c5

ENV ANT_VERSION=1.10.8
ENV ANT_HOME=/opt/ant-$ANT_VERSION
ENV PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH \
    ANT_SHA1=20658b765bed8a7c3d18daa71a108e15d1937da2

WORKDIR /dspace-src

# Download DSpace source and install Ant
RUN curl -fSL "https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/releases/download/dspace-${DSPACE_VERSION}/dspace-${DSPACE_VERSION}-src-release.tar.gz" -o dspace.tar.gz && \
    echo "${DSPACE_SHA1} *dspace.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c - && \
    tar -xz -f dspace.tar.gz --strip-components=1 && \
    rm -f dspace.tar.gz && \
    curl -fSL "https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-${ANT_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz" -o ant.tar.gz && \
    echo "${ANT_SHA1} *ant.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c - && \
    mkdir ${ANT_HOME} && \
    tar -xz -f ant.tar.gz -C ${ANT_HOME} --strip-components=1 && \
    rm -rf ant.tar.gz

# Copy in custom artifacts
COPY ./src/artifacts/ ./artifacts

# Copy in pom.xml files
COPY ./src/dspace/pom.xml                          ./dspace/
COPY ./src/dspace/modules/pom.xml                  ./dspace/modules/
COPY ./src/dspace/modules/jspui/pom.xml            ./dspace/modules/jspui/
COPY ./src/dspace/modules/utslib-copyright/pom.xml ./dspace/modules/utslib-copyright/
COPY ./src/dspace/modules/utslib-taglib/pom.xml    ./dspace/modules/utslib-taglib/

# Install custom artifacts and prime the Maven repository 
RUN mvn clean install --batch-mode --fail-never -f ./artifacts/JRis-master && \
    mvn install -P ${EXCLUDE_MODULES} --batch-mode --fail-never -T 5
```

Dockerfile.runtime:

```
ARG BUILD_IMAGE=our.git.url/dspace/build:latest

FROM ${BUILD_IMAGE} as build

# Copy in our source changes
COPY ./src/dspace ./dspace

# We don't use these modules, but they'll be built anyway if not excluded
ARG EXCLUDE_MODULES=!dspace-rdf,!dspace-xmlui,!dspace-sword

# Unzip the MaxMind GeoLite database (IP location stuff for Solr).
# (MaxMind changed their privacy policy so you now have to login to download,
# which makes it fail for the standard DSpace installation)
# Build dspace with our source changes and move it to the installation directory
# Build only our customisations (skip building the specified modules)
# Could multithread the maven build, but there's dependency resolution problems
RUN tar -zxf ./dspace/config/GeoLite2-City_20191224.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C ./dspace/config && \
    rm ./dspace/config/GeoLite2-City_20191224.tar.gz && \
    mvn package --batch-mode -P ${EXCLUDE_MODULES} -f ./dspace/pom.xml && \
    cd ./dspace/target/dspace-installer && \
    ant copy_webapps install_code

FROM tomcat:8-alpine
#FROM tomcat:8-jre8

ARG DSPACE_INSTALL_DIR=/dspace

ENV DSPACE_HOME=${DSPACE_INSTALL_DIR}

# Copy built source into this image
COPY --from=build ${DSPACE_INSTALL_DIR} ${DSPACE_INSTALL_DIR}

# Copy in our config overrides
# (These are not used in compilation, but are applied at runtime)
COPY ./src/local.cfg ${DSPACE_INSTALL_DIR}/config/

# Symlink all webapps and create temp upload directory
RUN ln -s ${DSPACE_INSTALL_DIR}/webapps/* ./webapps/
```

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade this cluster to current default version of GKE (1.16.13-gke.401)? Could you provide configuration files and steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us. We are reticent to upgrade further, given you can only upgrade one major release at a time - so we'd be performing two upgrades which is very time consuming. Also we have several other apps running in nodes on this cluster and we believe the risk of breaking them is too great and some things we use have been deprecated which involves substantial work re-jigging our gitlab CI/CD deployment process. I will post configuration files below.

Comment: Added config files to original question.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing the most verbose logging level in both DSpace and Tomcat, more information was available regarding the source of the Spring error.

The problem was with one of our custom factory classes. Error log extract:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'org.dspace.storage.bitstore.BitstreamStorageService' defined in file 
[/dspace/config/spring/api/bitstore.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 's3Store' while 
setting bean property 'stores' with key [TypedStringValue: value [0], target type [null]]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 's3Store' defined in file 
[/dspace/config/spring/api/bitstore.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 
's3ConnectionTTL' of bean class [org.dspace.storage.bitstore.S3BitStoreService]: Bean 
property 's3ConnectionTTL' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the 
parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

The offending property is writeable, has a valid getter and setter and getter and setter are both long type. I removed the property set code and just let it remain the default. Deployment works.

How simply upping k8s version could cause this error is beyond us. In pods with the previous GKE version exactly the same code executes fine.